# header and footer with reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, header, footer, reportlab

I have a problem with my code:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, PageTemplate, Frame, Paragraph, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

def header(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
    canvas.drawString(36, letter[1] - 36, "CABEÇA")
    canvas.restoreState()

def footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
    canvas.drawString(36, 36, "PÉZÃO")
    canvas.restoreState()

pdf_filename = "exemplo.pdf"

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_filename, pagesize=letter)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normal_style = styles["Normal"]

frame = Frame(36, 36, letter[0] - 72, letter[1] - 72)
template = PageTemplate(id='page_with_header_footer', frames=frame, onPage=header, onPageEnd=footer)

doc.addPageTemplates([template])

story = []

for i in range(10):
    story.append(Paragraph(f"Conteúdo da Página {i + 1}", normal_style))
    story.append(PageBreak())

story.pop()

doc.build(story)
```

I'm trying to generate a document with reportlab where all pages get header and footer, however, only my first page gets header and footer. I don't know what else to do :C

Comment: from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def MultiPage():

    c = canvas.Canvas('TESTE.pdf')

    for i in range(5):
        page_num = c.getPageNumber()
        text = "Essa página é a %s" % page_num
        c.drawString(100,50,text)
        c.showPage()
    c.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MultiPage()

Thias code creat 5 pages with the string 'Essa página é a %s' on footer!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code little bit, added extra method to append header footer on build, it's working now

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, PageTemplate, Frame, Paragraph, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

def header(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
    canvas.drawString(36, letter[1] - 36, "CABEÇA")
    canvas.restoreState()

def footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
    canvas.drawString(36, 36, "PÉZÃO")
    canvas.restoreState()

def _header_footer( canvas, doc):
        # Save the state of our canvas so we can draw on it
        canvas.saveState()
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

        # Header
        header(canvas, doc)

        # Footer
        footer(canvas, doc)
        # Release the canvas
        canvas.restoreState()

pdf_filename = "exemplo.pdf"

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_filename, pagesize=letter)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normal_style = styles["Normal"]

frame = Frame(36, 36, letter[0] - 72, letter[1] - 72)
template = PageTemplate(id='page_with_header_footer', frames=frame)

doc.addPageTemplates([template])

story = []

for i in range(10):
    story.append(Paragraph(f"Conteúdo da Página {i + 1}", normal_style))
    story.append(PageBreak())

story.pop()

doc.build(story, onFirstPage=_header_footer, onLaterPages=_header_footer)
```